# Override template edit account didn't work on front end

Tags: magento2, theme-overriding, template-override

I like to override `magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/edit.phtml` template, in my desktop it works but in our development server, I got this page

[image]

looks like there's inheritance not working
PS: We have a custom theme installed, luma theme with some modifications

so I created a module

In **Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_edit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="customer_account"/>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="head.components">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="customer_account_edit_head_components" template="Magento_Customer::js/components.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
        <action method="setPageTitle">
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Edit Account Information</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Edit" name="customer_edit" template="Vendor_ModuleName::form/edit.phtml" cacheable="false">
            <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

And in **Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/form/edit.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Edit $block */
?>
<form class="form form-edit-account" action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl('customer/account/editPost')) ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>" autocomplete="off">
<fieldset class="fieldset info">
    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
    <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Account Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
    <?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name')->setObject($block->getCustomer())->toHtml() ?>
    
    <?php $_dob = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Dob') ?>
    <?php $_taxvat = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Taxvat') ?>
    <?php $_gender = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Gender') ?>
    <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
        <?= $_dob->setDate($block->getCustomer()->getDob())->toHtml() ?>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()): ?>
        <?= $_taxvat->setTaxvat($block->getCustomer()->getTaxvat())->toHtml() ?>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php if ($_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
        <?= $_gender->setGender($block->getCustomer()->getGender())->toHtml() ?>
    <?php endif ?>
    
    <div class="field choice">
        <input type="checkbox" name="change_email" id="change-email" data-role="change-email" value="1" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Change Email')) ?>" class="checkbox" />
        <label class="label" for="change-email"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change Email')) ?></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="field choice">
        <input type="checkbox" name="change_password" id="change-password" data-role="change-password" value="1" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Change Password')) ?>"<?php if ($block->getChangePassword()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" />
        <label class="label" for="change-password"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change Password')) ?></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="field field-name-invoice_email">
        <label class="label" for="invoice_email"><span>Invoice Email</span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" id="invoice_email" name="invoice_email" value="<?php echo $block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('invoice_email')->getValue(); //echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getInvoice_Email()) ?>" title="Last Name" class="input-text required-entry" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true">
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="fieldset password" data-container="change-email-password">
    <legend class="legend"><span data-title="change-email-password"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change Email and Password')) ?></span></legend><br>
    <div class="field email required" data-container="change-email">
        <label class="label" for="email"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="email" data-input="change-email" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getCustomer()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field password current required">
        <label class="label" for="current-password"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Current Password')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="password" class="input-text" name="current_password" id="current-password" data-input="current-password" autocomplete="off" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field new password required" data-container="new-password">
        <label class="label" for="password"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('New Password')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password" id="password"
                data-password-min-length="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getMinimumPasswordLength()) ?>"
                data-password-min-character-sets="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getRequiredCharacterClassesNumber()) ?>"
                data-input="new-password"
                data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-customer-password':true}"
                autocomplete="off" />
            <div id="password-strength-meter-container" data-role="password-strength-meter" aria-live="polite">
                <div id="password-strength-meter" class="password-strength-meter">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password Strength')) ?>:
                    <span id="password-strength-meter-label" data-role="password-strength-meter-label">
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('No Password')) ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field confirm password required" data-container="confirm-password">
        <label class="label" for="password-confirmation"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Confirm New Password')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password_confirmation" id="password-confirmation"
                data-input="confirm-password"
                autocomplete="off" />
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<?= $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info') ?>
<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="primary">
        <button type="submit" class="action save primary" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Save')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Save')) ?></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="secondary">
        <a class="action back" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Go back')) ?></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<script>
require([
    "jquery",
    "mage/mage"
], function($){
    var dataForm = $('#form-validate');
    var ignore = <?= /* @noEscape */ $_dob->isEnabled() ? '\'input[id$="full"]\'' : 'null' ?>;
    
    dataForm.mage('validation', {
    <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.prop('id').search('full') !== -1) {
                var dobElement = $(element).parents('.customer-dob'),
                    errorClass = error.prop('class');
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                dobElement.find('.validate-custom').addClass(errorClass)
                    .after('<div class="' + errorClass + '"></div>');
            }
            else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        ignore: ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')'
    <?php else: ?>
        ignore: ignore ? ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')' : ':hidden'
    <?php endif ?>
    });

});
</script>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "[data-role=change-email], [data-role=change-password]": {
        "changeEmailPassword": {
            "titleChangeEmail": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeHtml(__('Change Email'))) ?>",
            "titleChangePassword": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeHtml(__('Change Password'))) ?>",
            "titleChangeEmailAndPassword": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeHtml(__('Change Email and Password'))) ?>"
        }
    },
    "[data-container=new-password]": {
        "passwordStrengthIndicator": {
            "formSelector": "form.form-edit-account"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

In **etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Wetag_InvoiceEmail" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
         <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
        <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        <module name="Magento_Cms"/>
        <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your module: **SR_MagentoCommunity**. Try following way:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_edit" template="SR_MagentoCommunity::form/edit.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

After that copy original phtml under your module, location:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/templates/form/edit.phtml

Comment: This is what i made, this works on my local installation but in server we have a custom theme and override is not working, it shows the edit.phtml content only

Comment: I found the error i was using a custm attribute <?php echo $block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('invoice_email')->getValue(); //echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getInvoice_Email()) ?> in my new text field value and it's not set

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled html minification there is a good chance that the version the frontend is using is not your local override but a version created from the override which is minified and stored elsewhere. If in doubt turn on template hints.

Comment: The problem was with a php error  <input type="text" id="invoice_email" name="invoice_email" value="<?php echo $block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('invoice_email')->getValue(); //echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getInvoice_Email()) ?>" title="Last Name" class="input-text required-entry" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true">
$block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('invoice_email') return null

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a module then you also need to overwrite the xml file: contact_index_index.xml

overwrite the contactForm block like:

```
<referenceBlock name="contactForm" template="Vendor_ModuleName::form/edit.phtml"/>
```

After this use your custom form file. It will work.